yocto install custom glibc version for qemu
I am having a yocto qemux86-64 qemu image, i am compiling a hello world cpp file in ubuntu host, when i run this binary in qemu environment i am getting the below glibc error
root@qemux86-64:~# ./a.out 
-sh: ./a.out: No such file or directory

When i check ldd of the binary
root@qemux86-64:~# ldd -v a.out 
./a.out: /lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.34' not found (required by ./a.out)
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fffa330f000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fdff36a0000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007fdff34d4000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/libm.so.6 (0x00007fdff3391000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 => /lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fdff3883000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fdff3378000)

    Version information:
    ./a.out:
        libstdc++.so.6 (GLIBCXX_3.4) => /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.34) => not found
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib/libc.so.6
    /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6:
        libm.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib/libm.so.6
        ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (GLIBC_2.3) => /lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
        libgcc_s.so.1 (GCC_4.2.0) => /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
        libgcc_s.so.1 (GCC_3.4) => /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
        libgcc_s.so.1 (GCC_3.3) => /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
        libgcc_s.so.1 (GCC_3.0) => /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.14) => /lib/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.6) => /lib/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.4) => /lib/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.18) => /lib/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.16) => /lib/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.3) => /lib/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.17) => /lib/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.3.2) => /lib/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib/libc.so.6
    /lib/libc.so.6:
        ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (GLIBC_2.3) => /lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
        ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (GLIBC_PRIVATE) => /lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
    /lib/libm.so.6:
        ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (GLIBC_PRIVATE) => /lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_PRIVATE) => /lib/libc.so.6
    /lib/libgcc_s.so.1:
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.14) => /lib/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib/libc.so.6
root@qemux86-64:~# 

So we can see there is glibc version difference
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.34) => not found
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib/libc.so.6

How can i add GLIBC_2.34 in my yocto image?

I have been working with yocto for almost a year. Although it is necessary more information to know exactly if that's the problem. My guess would be that you are missing the recipe glibc in the recipe of the package that generates a.out as runtime dependency. If you could create the binary, it is likely that you have something like this in the recipe of a.out:
DEPENDS = "glibc"

Yocto makes all the binaries in the host using cross compilation and only adds the dependent runtime packages to the final image to make the image as small as possible. In order to make it work in your image, you need to have the runtime version too. The message is clear, your image does not contain the glibc package. You only need to add a runtime dependency
RDEPENDS = "glibc"

If this is not working, show me the recipe of the a.out and the output of the following command:
bitbake-layers show-layers

The yocto documentation is one of the most complete Open Source projects that I have work with.

Term RDEPENDS
Recommend to read: What I wish I’d known about Yocto Project

Happy coding.
